# web scraping sismos, envío de mensajes bot telegram si se cumple condición, beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, scraping, beautifulsoup, telegram-bot

alguien me puede ayudar con mi código, es un bot de telegram el cuál envía mensajes de de un scraping a una web de sismos, me muestra el último sismo registrado cada 5 minutos, lo que necesito es que si pasado los  5 minutos registra el mismo sismo no envié el mensaje a telegram, de lo contrario si lo envíe.

Les dejo el código:

```
def bot_send_text(bot_message):
    
    bot_token = 'xxxxx'
    bot_chatID = 'xxxx'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message

    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()

def sismo_scraping():
    e = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sismologia.cl/ultimos_sismos.html").read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(e, 'html.parser')

    # Obt    enemos la tabla

    tabla_sismos = soup.find_all('table')[0]

    # Obtenemos todas las filas
    rows = tabla_sismos.find_all("tr")

    output_rows = []
    for row in rows:
        # obtenemos todas las columns
        cells = row.find_all("td")
        output_row = []
        if len(cells) > 0:
            for cell in cells:
                output_row.append(cell.text)
            output_rows.append(output_row)

    dataset = pd.DataFrame(output_rows)

    dataset.columns = [
        "Fecha Local",
        "Fecha UTC",
        "Latitud",
        "Longitud",
        "Profundidad [Km]",
        "Magnitud",
        "Referencia Geográfica",
    ]
    dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]] = dataset[["Latitud", "Longitud"]].apply(pd.to_numeric)
    
    dataset_filter = dataset[
            (-21.655 <= dataset["Latitud"])
            & (dataset["Latitud"] <= -19.370)
            & (-72.316 <= dataset["Longitud"])
            & (dataset["Longitud"] <= -68.426)
            ]
    
    string="A ocurrido un sismo en las cercanías de iquique" "\n"
    for column in dataset_filter.head(1).columns:
        string += column + " : " + str(dataset_filter[column].values[0]) + "\n"
    
    fecha_actual = dataset_filter.head(1)["Fecha Local"].values[0]
    fecha_actual2 = dataset_filter.head(1)["Fecha Local"].values[0]
    
    if fecha_actual != fecha_actual2:
        print(string)
    else:
        pass

def report():

    btc_price = f'{sismo_scraping()}'
    if btc_price == 0:
        bot_send_text(btc_price)
    else:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
        
    # schedule.every().day.at("12:34").do(report)
    schedule.every(5).minutes.do(report)

    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
```

elimine la funcion report() y agregue  main(), nose si estare en lo correcto.

```
def main():
    ultimo_sismo = (None)
    while True:
        text = f'{sismo_scraping()}'
        if (text) != ultimo_sismo:
            bot_send_text(text)
            ultimo_sismo = (text)
        time.sleep(20)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        
    main()
```

Comment: elimine la funcion reporte y agregue una llamada main() y dentro un ciclo while nose si estaré en lo correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Estas juntando demasiadas acciones en esas funciones, deberías compartimentarlo mejor para ver como quieres implementarlo; con eso en mente lo ideal seria poner una función para gestionar el estado del bot y otra para generar acciones en el telegram (que bien podría ser una clase por si sola) para poder llamarlas y aplicar el cambio que tuvieran. No tiene nada de malo el como estas pillado los datos, pero no se ve ideal ni para esa pagina ni para la cantidad de datos que tienes que manejar. Si miras este ejemplo, tienes que hacer algo parecido a las funciones update; algo que no necesitas hacer falta es mantener el historia ordenado, la pagina pone los últimos y si hay uno nuevo reemplazando el historia eliminara solo el ultimo

```
import http.client
import time
import re

class Bot_Teremotos:

    req_url = 'www.sismologia.cl'
    req_path = '/ultimos_sismos.html'
    req_headers = {
        # Lo correcto es marar que esto es un bot
        'User-Agent': 'Telegram Earthquake Bot 0.1',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml',
    }

    def parse_html(self, data):
        """
        [{
            'fecha' | 'url' | 'latitud' | 'longitud' |
            'profundidad' | 'magnitud' | 'referencia'
        }...]
        """
        infos = re.findall(
            r'<tr[ \w="]*>.+?</tr>',
            data, re.DOTALL
        )
        ret = []
        for i in infos:
            attrs = re.findall(r'<td>.+?</td>', i)
            if len(attrs) != 7:
                continue
            datos = []
            for a in attrs:
                datos.append(re.split(r' *</?td> *', a)[1])
            ret.append({
                'fecha': datos[1],
                'url': self.req_url + datos[0].split("\"")[1],
                'latitud': datos[2],
                'longitud': datos[3],
                'profundidad': datos[4],
                'magnitud': datos[5],
                'referencia': datos[6],
            })
        return ret

    def get_html_req(self):
        conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(self.req_url)
        conn.request(
            'GET', self.req_path,
            headers=self.req_headers
        )
        data = str(
            conn.getresponse().read(),
            encoding='ascii', errors='ignore'
        )
        conn.close()
        return data

    def __init__(self):
        # Deberias implementar sesiones
        # para no reenviar de nuevo unos
        self.historial = []

    def update_info(self):
        info = self.get_html_req()
        datos = self.parse_html(info)

        nuevo = []
        for n in datos:
            if n not in self.historial:
                nuevo.append(n)

        if nuevo:
            self.historial = datos
        return nuevo

    def update_telegram(self, nuevos):
        for n in nuevos:
            print('{0}: {1}'.format(
                n['fecha'], n['referencia']
            ))

    def update(self):
        nuevo = self.update_info()
        if nuevo:
            print(f'{len(nuevo)} nuevos')
            self.update_telegram(nuevo)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        bot = Bot_Teremotos()
        while 1:
            bot.update()
            time.sleep(60)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```